# ADDING MY INPUTS IN JAVA

Tags: java

im a bit confused of how to add my inputs that i entered , for example if i input (1,2,3,4) how can i get 10 ?

```
       int n1, n2;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
     n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
     System.out.print1n("The sum of those two numbers is");
     System.out.print1n(n1 + n2);
```

This way add a specific number of inputs, but what if i want to add like random inputs, e.g. some times i may enter 3 input, well sometimes 7 inputs...
I hope you got my point, and i appreciate any help :) thanks

Comment: how have you defined `kbd`?

Comment: What programming language is this? That's the most important thing to tag the question to, so people with the right skills read it.

Comment: sorry.. its java, am still a beginner , thats my third week at uni, so thats why i dont have that much of info.. 
ITS JAVA

Comment: You're asking us about syntax and compilation errors, and you deliberately post garbage code instead of the real one. There is no such thing as `for (i=0....i++) {` or  `for (i=0,...i++)` or `sysout...`in Java.

Comment: I did some edittitng on my code, I wrote the part where i am getting error , when I try to print out, it says that COUNT it says it cant find symbol

Comment: It's quite simple: you indent your code, then you post it, then you post the exact and complete error message you get. Nite that the message contains a line number, so the code of the method containing this line number should be in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you the exact problem. The variable `shots` is not in scope when you attempt to print it out.

```
   for (countd = 1; countd<= CupsOfCoffee; countd++)
   {
      System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup "+ countd);

      int shots = keyboard.nextInt();
   }
```

The variable shots is only declared within this for loop and cannot be referenced outside this loop. Indeed, being declared at the end of the loop, it is never actually used.

Comment: yea i tried declaring it outside the loop by typing (int shots=0;) before the for loop.. but i am not geeting what i want.. I wam getting all the outputs = to the last number i enter.. for example (if i enter 3,4,5) i get all the 3 answers 5 later, which is wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to read an `int` input by the user, you can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
```

If you need the value of an `int` that changes inside a loop after the loop is finished, declare the `int` before the loop:
`int a;`